# Running "adb shell" restarts ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3. Everything is up to date.
Running "adb shell" on Terminal **in Android Studio** generates the following:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
```

To reconnect the device, I have to run "adb kill-server" first.

This makes running shell commands impossible.

Could anyone offer a tip on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you possibly using two different versions of the adb binary?

Comment: How can I find out this.

Comment: Are you using the same adb binary that Android Studio uses? Do you use any tools that use their own adb binary?

Comment: I always use it in AS.  I cannot think of anything else related to ADB.  AS is the only environment used for Android app development.

Comment: When you run adb shell in Terminal, what adb binary do you use?

Comment: I run in the terminal of Android Studio, so I assume the ADB of Android studio is used.  I am going to edit the question to make this clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @FD_ You are right.Tthe culprit is the adb.exe of PhoenixSuit.  Please see my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android Studio Terminal run

```
$ $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb shell
```

this ensures you will be using the same `adb`.

Comment: My computer does not have the environment ANDROID_HOME environment.  I did a global search of adb.exe and ensure every copy is the same as the one from platform-tools, and the problem is solved.  I think the culprit is the adb.exe of PhoenixSuit.  I do not know why it is used by default.  I will try to figure out.  Thanks a lot.